# Dependency in android studio. Plugin Vs Library, DSL Vs API

Tags: android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, dsl, gradle-plugin

I used Firebase Cloud Message Service in my project. I read Firebase documentation for Integrate in android and see this line to add in **build.gradle** of project.

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

My question is:

Why we have to use google-service version **3.0.0** ? Instead latest is **9.4.0**.

Edition : Tnx [Gabriele](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016562/gabriele-mariotti). As per @[Gabriele](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38802309/5432730) its a plugin not library. So what is difference between Plugin and Library. What is different between DSL and API? Is API is depends on DSL or DSL is depends on API?

Comment: For better understanding, read this documentation http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/95/gradle-for-android#t=201608061131324504623

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse the buildscript dependencies with the library dependencies:

In your `buildscript` dependencies you are going to define the plugins used by your script. In this case you are adding the **google-services plugin**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

In the `dependencies` section you are going to define the libraries used.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'    
}
```

Comment: tnq. can u say what is difference between plugin and library.

Comment: The plugin is the plugin for gradle. It contains the DSL used in the build.gradle. The library contains the API to be used in the code.

Comment: okay so what is difference between DSL and API ? and is API is dependent on DSL ?

Comment: @Dharvikshah I don't know very well the DSL of the google play services plugin. in general these methods are used only by Gradle while you are building the project. The API are here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/packages and they don't depent by DSL.

Comment: Thats great. So, Plugin are at project level and Library are at Module level. Do you know how plugin works and why gradle need it ? By the way Tnx for share your great knowledge.

Comment: Gradle is a building system. You need plugins to use specific method. For example classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2' is the android plugin for gradle. Thanks to this plugin you can define some configuration as signing apk, flavors.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120315/discussion-between-dharvik-shah-and-gabriele-mariotti).